# Converting Cocos2d code to ARC issues

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, box2d-iphone

I am trying to ARC enable a project and I am having a few issues when selecting files for ARC.

In the Ball class, the following line,

```
ballBody->SetUserData(self);
```

gives the error,

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void *' with an Ivalue of type 'Ball *const__strong'
```

In the Enemy.mm class, the following line,

```
enemyBody->SetUserData(enemySprite);
```

gives the error,

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void *' with an Ivalue of type 'CCPhysicsSprite*__strong'
```

In Enemy.h I have defined the above as:

```
b2Body* enemyBody;
CCPhysicsSprite* enemySprite; (in Enemy.m)
```

How can I solve these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bridge casting:

```
ballBody->SetUserData((__bridge void*)self);
enemyBody->SetUserData((__bridge void*)enemySprite);
```

and the reverse:

```
CCPhysicsSprite* enemySprite = (__bridge CCPhysicsSprite*)enemyBody->GetUserData();
```